# Sentencia if no compara con la linea del archivo

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy tratando de verificar si es que un producto que ingresa el usuario es igual al que esta en el inventario pero cuando ingreso el articulo no entra en la sentencia if y pasa directo a la pregunta del do-while que podria hacer para que entre en la sentencia if, el producto[] se llena con el contenido del inventario que es un archivo que esta leyendo

```
entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("FACTURA");
                System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre completo: ");
                nom=entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Ingrese su numero de cedula: ");
                dni=entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Ingrese la fecha: ");
                fecha=entrada.nextLine();
                entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("INVENTARIO");
                System.out.println("Producto                      Cant       Precio Unitario");
                System.out.println("--------------------         ------      ---------------");
                while (entrada1.hasNextLine()) {
                producto=entrada1.nextLine().split(":");
                    if (producto[0].length()>30) {
                        producto[0]=producto[0].substring(0,30);
                    }
                    System.out.printf ("%-23s %,10d %,15.2f%n", producto[0],Integer.parseInt(producto[1]),Float.parseFloat(producto[2]));   
                }
                do {
                    System.out.println("Elija los articulos");
                    art=entrada.nextLine();
                    if (producto[0].equals(art)) {
                        System.out.println("¿Cuántos desea llevar?");
                        cant=entrada.nextInt();
                        do {                                
                            if (cant>Integer.parseInt(producto[1])) {
                                System.out.println("Su pedido es superior al stock disponible");
                                System.out.println("Vuelva a ingresar la cantidad");
                            }else{
                                precioCant=(int)(float)(cant*Integer.parseInt(producto[2]));
                            }
                        } while (cant<Integer.parseInt(producto[1]));
                      }
                    
                    System.out.println("¿Desea agregar más articulos?");
                    agArt=entrada.nextLine();
                }while (agArt.equals("Si"));
```

[image: Este es el resultado que me presenta]

[image: Esta es la primera parte del codigo]

Comment: Con esta info esta un poco difícil ver el problema, porque faltan datos. Por ejemplo, ese vector de productos donde lo cargas??. Otra cosa, vos estas utilizando el .equals, recorda que este método distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas. Agrega un poco mas de info. Podes probar haciendo debug a ver que valor tiene al momento de entrar a evaluar en el if, si no esta entrando es porque no se cumple la condición, no hay mucha vuelta que darle. Fíjate que el vector puede estar vacío, o fíjate el tema de las mayusculas, etc.

Comment: `producto` solo guarda la datos del último elemento leído del fichero.